# The $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ double coset of diagonal matrix

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, hecke-algebras

I have a trouble proving that:
For $k\in \mathbb{N}$, the double coset
\begin{align*} SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})\begin{pmatrix} k & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})\end{align*}
is consisting of the matrices \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} with integer entries having gcd 1 and of determinant $k$. I already know that the smith normal form of $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ gives a matrix $\gamma_{1}, \gamma_{2}\in GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\gamma_{1} \,\text{diag}(k,1)\,\gamma_{2}$ is equal to \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}. How can i make $\gamma_{1},\gamma_{2}$ are contained in $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$? Or is there any other way to prove the statement above?

Comment: remark that both $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ have the same sign,so if both of them have determinent $-1$, just replace $\gamma_1$ by $\gamma_1 D$ and $\gamma_2$ by $D\gamma_2$,where $D$ is the diagonal matrix ,whose diagonal consists of $1,-1$

Comment: Bezout's Lemma may be useful.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for your comment :) I think it will be helpful.